# Loading large images in XNA (Monogame), very unstable

Tags: c#, xna

In my game I'm trying to load very large 10,000 by 10,000 png images (they need to be that large because I'm using large non-repeating 4k textures as backgrounds), however loading them using

```
Texture2D[] CMap = new Texture2D[10]; //This texture is 4k 10,000*10,000
Texture2D[] Map = new Texture2D[10];  //This texture is just 2,500* 2,500, it's for collision

...

Map[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(PathString);
CMap[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(cPathString);
```

Is very hit or miss. Every now and then I get this error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Additional information: This image format is not supported
```

How I can fix this error is by simply cutting and pasting the declarations somewhere else in the same area but before or after other declarations. I'm guessing this is a memory management issue overlook with XNA (I'm actually using Monogame) having a hard time handling such large textures.

Sometimes it loads the first two map textures but then gives me an error for the third one after that, or the one after that, so I know the code mostly works it's just very unstable for some reason. So is there something I can do to fix this?

Also, I'm loading these textures during runtime. All my maps at once would hog ram I'd imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe XNA only supports textures up to the size of 4096x4096. Any larger than that and you have to split up your textures.